# Mysql customise order by with group by

Tags: mysql, sql

When I

```
SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE id = 2321 order by color asc, color = 49, color = 2;
```

this will return all which color = 2, then color = 49 then all others color.

But I need only the group by result which I then

```
SELECT * FROM table_A WHERE id = 2321 GROUP BY color ORDER BY color asc, color = 49, color = 2;
```

it will return group by result but have disregard the order

My question is how to I return color which start from 2, then 49, then other and group the 'color'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP BY` is not needed here. All you need is to use `FIELD()`

```
ORDER BY FIELD(color, 49, 2) DESC
```

this will sort with `Color = 2` first on the list, followed by `49` then other colors.

Comment: if this does not work, please do add some records with your desired result.,

Comment: this will output ALL items which color = 2 and subsequent, but I need to group the 'color'

Comment: By the way If I included GROUP BY in your answer then it works! So I will be accepting your answer

Answer (score 0):

If you care for the order of the rest of the colors you can use `CASE`

```
SELECT color 
  FROM table_A 
 WHERE id = 2321 
 GROUP BY color
 ORDER BY CASE color 
            WHEN 2 THEN 1 
            WHEN 49 THEN 2
            ELSE color + 50
          END
```

This will sort `2` first, `49` second, and then other colors **ordered** `ASC`.
That's assuming that color is always positive `int`.

**[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8140/6)**